# Using backreferences in java regular expressions adjacent to digits

Tags: java, regex

I want to use a regexp replace with back references
If the target string is something like:

```
"$1 123"
```

every thing works fine.
but if I want a target string like:

```
"$1123"
```

It wont work.

in perl, you can use

```
"${1}123"
```

To distinguish between the back reference an adjacent numbers - is there a java equivalent?

**EDIT**

If have time stamps of the format

```
YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
```

like:

```
20130811123000
```

and I want to reset the hours, minutes, and seconds to get

```
20130811000000
```

What I would like to do is

```
String newstring = timestamp.replaceFirst("(\\d{8}))\\d{6}","${1}000000");
```

Comment: Post your Java `Pattern`, your input `String` and your expected results.

Comment: Why you need regex for this? `String newStr = "20130811123000".substring(0, 8) + "000000";`

Comment: The regex in your code sample is syntactically invalid. But beside that, what exactly is not working correctly with `String newstring = timestamp.replaceFirst("(\\d{8})\\d{6}","$1000000");`? Java treats `$10` as "backreference 1, followed by a literal `0`" if there are fewer than 10 capturing groups in your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the replacement as:

```
"$1\\123"
```

Comment: refer to this articale on Regex,You will find detail explanation along with examples. http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 1):

`$12` would refer to the 12th group if it exists, or 1st group if there are less than 12 backreferences.

So, in `$1123` `$1` if only one group captured,`$11` if more than 11 groups captured and so on

[reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems an escape works.

See this case:

```
String input = "abcd";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(a)bcd(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?", "$1123"));
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(a)bcd(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?(e)*?", "$1\\123"));
```

Output:

```
23
a123
```

In this case I have an ambiguity between back-referenced group 1 and back-referenced group 11. 
In the 1st print I don't escape the back-reference, so group 11 is likely to be interpreted, and it's empty.
In the 2nd print I escape the replacement after the back-reference to group 1.